# Why is SQL function changing decimal places to all zeros?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Ok I have a number that is an nvarchar and has 2 decimal places.  If I run it through a very simple function it changes all of the decimal places to zeros and I am not sure why or how to stop it.

Here is the basic function (actually part of a larger function, but this is what is causing my issue).

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[z_test](@amt as nvarchar)
RETURNS decimal(18,4)
BEGIN 
declare @amt1 as decimal(18,4)
set @amt1=cast(@amt as decimal(18,4))
return @amt1
END
```

So if I run this SQL statement

```
select cast('3.48' as decimal(18,4)), dbo.z_test('3.48')
```

I would expect the columns returned to be the same.  However what I get is
3.4800  3.0000

Any ideas on why this happens or how I can change it?  This is in SQL Server 2005.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to post the entire function? I can't see an issue with the snippet you've provided

Answer (score 3):

You should specify a length for `nvarchar` in your function parameters, otherwise it will assume a length of 1 in this case, truncating your input:

```
(@amt as nvarchar(10))
```

Comment: Ah.. yes I do rememnber running into that before with some straight nvarchar fields.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your input variable is being truncated.

According to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

*When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.*

Give the `NVARCHAR` a size and your function will work as expected:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[z_test](@amt as nvarchar(10))
RETURNS decimal(18,4)
BEGIN 
declare @amt1 as decimal(18,4)
set @amt1=cast(@amt as decimal(18,4))
return @amt1
END
```